# Server-Side Request Forgery Fortify Fix

Tags: c#, web-services, fortify

I'm trying to call a webservice. This webservice call depends on the user input as the URL.

The URL looks like follows:

```
https://someurl.com/somefunction/{userinput}
```

And my function looks like this

```
public async Task<Data> GetData(string input)
{
    try
    {
        Address = BaseAddress; // https://someurl.com/somefunction/{userinput}
        Address = Address.Replace("{userinput}", input);
        ....
        WebService ws = await base.GetData(httpClient, serverIPaddress);
        ....
    }
}
```

And I get the security error from Fortify

> Server-Side Request Forgery (Input Validation and Representation, Data
>   Flow)
>
> The function GetAsync() on line 122 initiates a network connection to
>   a third-party system using user-controlled data for resource URI. An
>   attacker may leverage this vulnerability to send a request on behalf
>   of the application server since the request will originate from the
>   application server's internal IP address.

Here are the recommendations:

Recommendations:

> Do not establish network connections based on user-controlled data and
>   ensure that the request is being sent to the expected destination. If
>   user data is necessary to build the destination URI, use  a level of
>   indirection: create a list of legitimate resource names that a user is
>   allowed to specify, and only allow the user to select from the list.
>   With this approach the input provided by the user is never used
>   directly to specify the resource name.
>
> In some situations this approach is impractical because the set of
>   legitimate resource names is too large or too hard to keep track of.
>   Programmers often resort to blacklisting in these situations.
>   Blacklisting selectively rejects or escapes potentially dangerous
>   characters before using the input. However, any such list of unsafe
>   characters is likely to be incomplete and will almost certainly become
>   out of date. A better approach is to create a whitelist of characters
>   that are allowed to appear in the resource name and accept input
>   composed exclusively of characters in the approved set.
>
> Also, if required, make sure that the user input is only used to
>   specify a resource on the target system but that the URI scheme, host,
>   and port is controlled by the application. This way the damage that an
>   attacker is able to do will be significantly reduced.

But the thing is that I really need to change `{userinput}` based on the supplied data from user. `{userinput}` will be a string with a certain maximum length.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you able to solve the issue?

Comment: @HamzaKhanzada, end up I validate the input against database, and supply the returned value from database to be assigned to userinput.

Comment: There is another hack I found to fix this without going through the database. let me post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

After so much research and hit and try attempts, I finally got this working by appending the input in the `BaseAddress`

The sample code looks like

```
public async Task<Data> GetData(string input)
{
    try
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://someurl.com/somefunction/{input}");
        var content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("");
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(content);
    }
}
```